# How can I implement AOS with React

Tags: reactjs, aos.js

I have this code in my HTML template:

```
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
```

How can I implement this with AOS in react?

When I go to the [AOS documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos), I can't see the option for data-spy and data-target to replace it in react.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/49